# String in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array like this :

```
["444c-0300-0b29-1817", "444c-0300-0b29-0715,444c-0300-0b29-0720"]
```

I want to make like this:

```
["444c-0300-0b29-1817", "444c-0300-0b29-0715", "444c-0300-0b29-0720"]
```

I need a best practise..
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can also use `var arrayVal = ["444c-0300-0b29-1817", "444c-0300-0b29-0715,444c-0300-0b29-0720"]; arrayVal = arrayVal.join().split(",");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
var data = ["444c-0300-0b29-1817", "444c-0300-0b29-0715,444c-0300-0b29-0720"],
    single = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.split(','));
    }, []);

console.log(single);
```

ES6

```js
var data = ["444c-0300-0b29-1817", "444c-0300-0b29-0715,444c-0300-0b29-0720"],
    single = data.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a.split(',')), []);

console.log(single);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this job;

```js
var arr = ["444c-0300-0b29-1817", "444c-0300-0b29-0715,444c-0300-0b29-0720"],
    brr = [].concat(...arr.map(s => s.split(",")));
console.log(brr);
```